# Extracting Every Nth Element of A Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, seq

I want to extract every nth element of row for each row in a matrix, here is my code:

```
x <- matrix(1:16,nrow=2)
x
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16
```

I have tried:

```
sapply(x, function(l) x[seq(1,8,2)])
```

which clearly fails.

I want to pull every 2nd value from "x" the desired output would be something like...

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    7   11   15
[2,]    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: Or `x[,c(FALSE, TRUE)]`

Comment: @akrun your solution is one of the smartest R-things I've ever seen.

Comment: @SabDeM Thanks, but it may be slow compared to `seq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it:

This gives you what you need

```
x[,seq(2, 8, 2)]
```

or, more generally

```
x[,seq(2, ncol(x), 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing that must have messed something very simple up. Thanks for the quick response.